# Android: If statement based on checkbox not being checked

Tags: android, ischecked

I think this is really easy but I am fairly new to android development so thanks in advance

If the first one is checked I generate a random number for text Item 1. If both the checkboxs are checked I generate text for the second text. I was wondering what is the most efficient way to do this

Here is the snippet that I need help with

```
if(edit1.isChecked()){
    text1.setText(String1[randomInt]);
}

if(edit1.isChecked() && edit2.isChecked()){
    text2.setText(String1[randomInt]);
}
```

Obviously, the first statement will show true in both. basically is there a way to say if edit2 is false?

Comment: thanks anywas..I looked it up and there is no way to do it

Comment: mine pleasuer. i also love basic things like this. thank you for this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
edit2.isChecked()=false;

if(edit1.isChecked() && (edit2.isChecked()==false)) {
    text2.setText(String1[randomInt]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks I knew it was something so basic. I am getting better but I still miss basic things like this

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position, long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.chkSelected);
        TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
//        pi = (PackageInfo) arg0.getItemAtPosition(position);
        cb.performClick();
        if (cb.isChecked()) {
            studentList.add(tv.getText().toString());
        } else if (!cb.isChecked()) {
            studentList.remove(tv.getText().toString());
        }
    }
```